# AngularJS: Function in controller called multiple times by template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, angularjs-digest

I know this question has been asked in here before it seem that all the answers is either quotes from AngularJS doc or doesn't provide with a solution (not a solution I understand anyway) so I'll give it a try once more.

My experience with Angular is relatively new, started out some month ago, so please forgive my ignorance if this is basic knowledge.

Within a list of posts (iterate by using `ng-repeat`) I've a special "share to" button.
The link on the button (href) depends on three different factors: `post_id`, `user_id`, `network`.

I'm trying to do this, within my `ng-repeat="post in posts"`

`<a href ng-href="{{genShareUrl(post.id,post.author_id,'fb')}}>Facebook</a>`

The original function which perform the generation is in a factory, I just use `genShareUrl` as a middleman function between controller and factory.

When logging out from the `genShareUrl` function in the post controller, I see this function is called multiple times.
Actually, if I run it on full scale on all posts fetched from backend, my app just come to a halt. No error, just eternal loading (I figured that I might have inadvertently triggered some kind of eternally $digest loop I'm unfamiliar with or at least some exponentially call pattern).

I've tried to recreate the scenario with a simple example:
http://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/xVexRa

Here I can see, that the function first is called twice, then four times - which indicates to me that the digest cycle is triggered multiple time.

In such a case as described, how would I best go about generating some value in a link? Is this the best practice? If no, how or could you give me an example on how to refactor the code.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses dirty checking to achieve two-way binding, all two-way binding watchers would be evaluated in each digest cycle, that is the reason `genShareUrl` be called multiple times, to avoid this happened, you could use one-way binding in your template:

```
<a href ng-href="{{::genShareUrl(post.id,post.author_id,'fb')}}>Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like suggest a best practice for your case:

> Resolve start-up logic for a controller in an activate function.

So, you can add an `activate` function as follows:

```js
activate();

function activate() {
    angular.forEach($scope.json, function (p) {
        p.btoa = $scope.func(p.id);
    });
}
```

After that, you can update your template and use:

```html
<div ng-repeat="person in json">
    <a href ng-href="/user/{{person.btoa}}">{{person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName}}</a>    
  </div>
```

In that way you'll avoid multiple calls to your function due to two-way data binding behavior.

Take a look following links:

- [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controller-activation-promises)
- Your example updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGZBEX